# Displaying coordinates of the mouse

Tags: assembly, emu8086, x86-16

The following code shows numbers from 0-9. Then it will start printing equivalent ASCII numbers.

Question is how to convert them to back to decimal?

Here is what I have done so far:

**Assembly Code**

```
data segment     
ends    
stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends    
code segment
start:  
L1 :  
  mov ah,2
    mov bh,0
    mov dl,0
    int 10h
mov ax,1
int 33h
mov ax,3
int 33h 
mov ah,2  
mov al,cl
mov cl,8
div cl
sub al,16  
mov cl,10
div cl
  push dx
LEA dx,ax
mov ah,2
int 21h
 pop DX 
 mov al,dl
 mov dl,8
 div dl
 sub al,16
 mov dl,10
 div dl
    push dx
 LEA DX,Ax
 mov ah,2
 int 21h
    pop dx 
                loop l1
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h  
ends
end start
```

Comment: You need to convert the numbers to ASCII before printing them. Your calculation for the first character you print is `(CL / 8 - 16) / 10` which, aside from the fact that it's missing the ASCII conversion, is probably not what you want. There is no `LEA dx, ax` instruction, your assembler should've rejected it.

Comment: @RossRidge This is one of this emu8086 peculiarities. For whatever reason they chose to accept `LEA reg, reg` and emit `mov reg, reg`. In this case it would emit `MOV dx, ax`. I'm in total agreement that you shouldn't use `LEA dx, ax` (makes no sense), but emu8086 won't reject it :(

Comment: Instead of converting it back to decimal, it's easier to back up the value in RAM and reload it.